# Perl:How to change values in global hash in sub-routine

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I have a global hash

```
our %employee = (
    'ename'=>"rahul",
    'eno'=>"25",
);
```

later I want to use it in a subroutine wid different values

```
sub emp
{
    print ("$employee->'ename' = 'satish'");
}
```

but this is not happening can you please suggest me what is wrong here..?

Answer (score 4):

`%employee` is a hash not a hash reference. So try to modify the value like `$employee{'ename'}= "Satish";`

```
use strict;

our %employee = ( 
    'ename' => "rahul",
    'eno'   => "25",
);

sub emp {
    print "Original Value: $employee{'ename'} \n";
    $employee{'ename'} = "Satish";
    print "Modified Value: $employee{'ename'}\n";
}

emp();
```

Output:

```
Original Value: rahul
Modified Value: Satish
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you would modify another hash value.

Say you have a package like so:

```
package TestPack;

use warnings;
use strict;

our %employee = (
    ename => 'rahul',
    eno   => 25,
);
```

You could modify the `hash` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use TestPack;

print "name: $TestPack::employee{'ename'}\n";

$TestPack::employee{'ename'} = "Chris";
print "name: $TestPack::employee{'ename'}\n";
```

The output:

```
$ ./test.pl 
name: rahul
name: Chris
```

Although it probably isn't best to handle the data directly when working on larger projects with many people, instead you can have something like "accessors/mutators" in `TestPack`:

```
sub get_value {
    my $val = shift;

    if( exists($employee{$val}) ) {
        return $employee{$val};
    } else {
        return "No such value: $val";
    }
}

sub update_ename {
    my $ename = shift;

    $employee{'ename'} = $ename;
}
```

The other module/script could add something like this:

```
my $new_new_ename = "Mike";

TestPack::update_ename($new_new_ename);
print "name: ", TestPack::get_value('ename'), "\n";
print "name: ", TestPack::get_value('foobar'), "\n";
```

Output:

```
name: Mike
name: No such value: foobar
```